# Angularjs auto prefixes forward slash

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redirect

If I hit the url say

`www.xyz.com/home#route-1`

AngularJS automatically re-directs it to

`www.xyz.com/home#/route-1`

That is - it prefixes the route with a `/` (forward slash)

Why is it happening and how can I stop making it do this?

**Update**
What I am really looking for is that angular should not attach the forward slash neither remove the hash sign.

Comment: Have you found a solution ?

Comment: @Bigood checkout the answers below.

Comment: You said you don't want to *"remove the hash sign."* though, but the solution pointed here removes it in my case ; that's why I asked you so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Tushar I'm not sure if you've figured out a solution but I came across your scenario too and no luck with googling. Eventually I figured out it's a rather simple fix, I've added : -

```
angular.config(function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false,
        rewriteLinks: false
    });
})
```

And it just stop appending the forward slash (/) prefix to my hash anchor. Everything remains as what we're familiar with (no replacing of URL with hash or what-not).

Comment: this is work but when i refresh page at that time it display "Object not found!" page any solution for that

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an anchor in your AngularJS app, you should use the `$anchorScroll` service.

```
"controller"

function ScrollCtrl($scope, $location, $anchorScroll) {
  $scope.gotoBottom = function (){
    // set the location.hash to the id of
    // the element you wish to scroll to.
    $location.hash('bottom');

    // call $anchorScroll()
    $anchorScroll();
  }
}

"html"

<div id="scrollArea" ng-controller="ScrollCtrl">
  <a ng-click="gotoBottom()">Go to bottom</a>
  <a id="bottom"></a> You're at the bottom!
</div>
```

[You could see this working in AngularJS documentation.](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.3/docs/api/ng.%24anchorScroll)

If you want to prettify AngularJS urls you could enabled html5Mode:

```
.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'partials/home.html',
            controller : mainController
        })
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl : 'partials/about.html',
            controller : mainController
        })
        .when('/contact', {
            templateUrl : 'partials/contact.html',
            controller : mainController
        });

    // use the HTML5 History API
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

[You could see more here](http://scotch.io/quick-tips/js/angular/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag)

Comment: no i have nothing to do with scrolling on the page. Its just simple routes that are getting messed up.

Comment: but this is the normal functionality of angularjs routes. I thought that you were having problems to anchor. In my case I have the index.html with AngularJS app and I could enter it from http://localhost:9768/index.html#/login and http://localhost:9768/#/login

Comment: You could use the html5Mode to prettify the routes, I edited the post

Comment: Is there no way to override this behavior?

Comment: Yes, You could use the html5Mode to prettify the routes, this is the way to override it. And the routes will be www.xyz.com/route-1. `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`

Comment: But i want to keep the # sign. I mean it should not convert /home#route to /home#/route.