# $location.hash() troubleshooting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

So I want to have a navigation bar that controls the location and only shows pages that are visible. A bit like the default "office" bootstrap example, but hiding sections that are not visible and not sliding. I thought I'd do it as an example in Angular because I need to hook in some stuff in the nav bar with a service callback... but basics first.

Very simply, I want the nav controller to read the hash to determine which tab is visible, then when I click on a different link, i want it to update the hash to match.

A real simple controller and disabling the autoclick funtionality:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".navbar a").on('click', function(event) {
        // Prevent default anchor click behavior
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});

app.controller('NavCtrl', [ "$scope", "$location", function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.activeTab = "home";

    console.log("hash: " + $location.hash());

    $scope.setActiveTab = function(t) {
        $scope.activeTab = t;
        $location.hash(t);
    };

    $scope.isActiveTab = function(t) {
        return $scope.activeTab == t;
    };
} ]);
```

Then, we want a navigation bar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home" data-ng-click="setActiveTab('')"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span> <span class="visible-xs size-indicator">XS</span> <span class="visible-sm size-indicator">SM</span> <span class="visible-md size-indicator">MD</span> <span class="visible-lg size-indicator">LG</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li data-ng-class="{active:isActiveTab('about')}"><a href="#about" data-ng-click="setActiveTab('about')">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li data-ng-class="{active:isActiveTab('contact')}"><a href="#contact" data-ng-click="setActiveTab('contact')">CONTACT</a></li>
                <li data-ng-class="{active:isActiveTab('profile')}"><a href="#profile" data-ng-click="setActiveTab('profile')"> <span data-ng-hide="imgsrc.length>0" class="profile-icon glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> <span data-ng-hide="imgsrc.length==0"> <img class="profile-icon img-circle" data-ng-hide="imgsrc.length==0" data-ng-src="{{imgsrc}}" />
                    </span>
                </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

When I go to the page with http://server/#about, the page immediately rewrites this to http://server/#/about and the console logging shows a blank hash. There is nothing there that should be rewriting the hash to #/whatever.

What am I missing???

### EDIT

I have also tried the HTML5 enabled mode as per one of the answers. and while it does less stuffing up of the URL, it does routing and still doesn't work as I need.

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.config(function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false,
        rewriteLinks: false
    });
});
```

This seems to work fine in the bootstrap office demo template but I can't seem to unpick it.

### EDIT 2

If you do `http://server/##about` all the navigation seems to work. Maybe its a bit broke because I have ng-app tag on the body?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23785002/angularjs-auto-prefixes-forward-slash), you need to activate HTML5 mode, it should stop adding the '/' at the beginning :

```
angular.module('moduleName').config(function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false,
        rewriteLinks: false
    });
})
```

Comment: Not sure where to do this, everywhere I tried I get: Uncaught TypeError: angular.config is not a function. Why is it not enabled in HTML5 mode anyway, I would have thought it would detect the doctype or be that by default.

Comment: I'm sorry I just copied and pasted a code, I edited it.

Comment: Also, this doesn't cause a problem in the Bootstrap Office template. Ah, found out where to add it, and it still doesn't work. as I want, still blank hash when I check

Comment: Hum... I think there is some kind of conflict with how Angular usually deals with URLs. Here I suppose you don't use any angular routes. If you really don't want to, you can simply use `window.location.hash`, it should work as you expect but you won't be able to deal with angular routes after that.

Comment: Yeah, I will need routes later I think. Hmm. My example does work if you do http://server/##about (using the double hash)

Comment: Ah okay then use very simple routes for now then simply add your hash ('server/#/#about')